# Grouping Elements in the List python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Python throws an error on appending a value to the nested list. I am trying to sort `list` by the same number. If I have an input `([1, 2, 1, 1, 2])` I want it to be placed in nested list as `[[1, 1, 1] ,[2, 2]`

```
def find_it(seq):
    seq_count = [[]]
    seq_copy = seq
    for i in range(0, len(seq)):
        for k in seq_copy:
            if seq[i] == k:
                seq_count[i].append(k)
    print(seq_count)


find_it([1, 2, 1, 1, 2])
```

Required Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1] ,[2, 2]]
```

Comment: seq_count[i] here you have only 1 nested list item in list seq_count, but you're accessing i th item of seq_count, so that's why you're getting error.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do.. so, that we can contribute to your code.

Comment: btw you can replace `range(0, len(seq))` with `range(len(seq))`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why do you need a nested list there?

Comment: I am trying to sort list by the same number. If I have an input ([1, 2, 1, 1, 2]) I want it to be placed in nested list as [[1, 1, 1] ,[2, 2]

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way of doing this would be to use `Counter` from the `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter
seq_count = [[i]*c for i,c in Counter(seq).items()]
```

yields `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]`

If you want to use explicit looping, for each `i` in seq you would first have to loop over `seq_count`, checking if there is an item which has `i` as its first element. If so, appending to that sublist, and if not spawning a new sublist. If you want to go this route, it would make more sense to initialize `seq_count` as `[]` rather than `[[]]`. Only spawn a sublist when you have an item that needs it.